# Ruby/Rails 3: How do I use multiple nested includes in an AR where query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**Edit:**Last paragraph added to briefly describe the problem set--the data model is complex, but the problem set seems to dictate it. Maybe someone else has a better idea!

I've been working on this problem for more than a month now as I have been learning Ruby on Rails, and I've yet to discover a resolution. I'm using Rails 3.09, Ruby 1.9.2, and PG SQL 8.0. I'm currently unable to upgrade to Rails 3.1 due to gem dependencies.

I have a complex data model for a game that involves collecting rumors about activities of hirelings within the game and displaying the content of rumors to the end user. When a user selects a hireling, they should be able to view all rumors within the database where that hireling is either the actor or the target of the action the rumor is about.

Here is the query in question:

```
@rumorEvents = current_webuser.player.rumor_events.includes(:rumor_instances =>[:actor, :target]).where(
            "(hirelings.id=? AND ( (\"suspectedActor\"=hirelings.name) OR (\"suspectedTarget\"=hirelings.name)))", 
            session[:selectedHireling]).
            paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1).order('"rumor_instances".updated_at DESC')
```

As it stands above, this query returns all rumor events where session[:selectedHireling] is an actor, but does not return rumor events where it is a target. If I change
        includes(:rumor_instances =>[:actor, :target])
to
        includes(:rumor_instances =>[:target])
it will return all events where he is a target, but not an actor.

**How can I return all rumor events for both actor and target?**

Here are the relevant sections of the models:

```
class RumorEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :player
has_many :rumor_event_rumor_instance_rels, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :rumor_instances, :through => :rumor_event_rumor_instance_rels
    suspectedActor       :string(255)
    suspectedTarget      :string(255)


class RumorInstance < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :player
belongs_to :game_event
has_one :rumor_actor_rel, :dependent => :destroy
has_one :actor, :through => :rumor_actor_rel, :source => :hireling
has_one :rumor_target_rel, :dependent => :destroy
has_one :target, :through => :rumor_target_rel, :source => :hireling

class Hireling < ActiveRecord::Base
#  id                   :integer         not null, primary key
#  name                 :string(255)
```

All rel models are basic, and known working. Here's an example:

```
# Table name: rumor_event_rumor_instance_rels
#
#  id                :integer         not null, primary key
#  rumor_event_id    :integer
#  rumor_instance_id :integer
#  created_at        :datetime
#  updated_at        :datetime
#

class RumorEventRumorInstanceRel < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :rumor_event
belongs_to :rumor_instance
end
```

Rumors about Game Events verbal description (from designer).

When a game event occurs, 100% accurate and complete information is stored about that act, and kept available for 3 game days. As Hirelings and Players visit the cities near the event's location, they will be able to learn partials of information about the event (rumor instances), which range from "someone was assassinated" to "The Merchant of Venice, Sir Sellsalot was assassinated by Malagant, a hireling that serves (player) Mr. Brown". A player may collect multiple rumor instances about the same event from multiple sources, each with different levels of information, and different levels of accuracy (including in some cases false information).

The code above illustrates the "top level" of information, which acts as a container for all information partials (rumor instances) about a particular event.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a project with a similar scenario to test on.  Off the top of my head, though, includes tags on a relation are cumulative.  You should just be able to include 2 include tags:

```
includes(:rumor_instances => :target).includes(:rumor_instances => :actor)
```

I think there may be something else.  Your data model strikes ne as convoluted.  It seems to me that a player should be able to go straight to a rumor instance (which I think is a poor name for what it seems to be representing) through a rumor.  What you're doing is complicated enough that I 'smell' something wrong in your data model.  Either way, hope this helps.

Comment: I've attempted this already--it simply cuts the results down to zero, as there is no rumor event where a a hireling is both the actor and the target.It's a complex simulation--I trimmed it down to the bare necessity to illustrate the issue.